# Ruby #select, but only select a certain number

Tags: ruby, select

Whats the best way in Ruby to do something like `my_array.select(n){ |elem| ... }`, where the `n` means "I only want `n` elements returned, and stop evaluating after that number is reached"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no avoiding a traditional loop if you're using stock 1.8.7 or 1.9.2...

```
result = []
num_want = 4
i = 0
while (elem = my_array[i]) && my_array.length < num_want
  result << elem if elem.some_condition
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: You could also do my_array.each, and then break when you have selected num_want elements (functionally the exact same but a bit more ruby-ish)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

`my_array.select(n) { |elem| elem.meets_condition? }.take(n)`

However, this will still evaluate all items.

If you have a lazy enumerator, you could do this in a more efficient manner.

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/100 shows an attempt at enabling this feature.

Comment: You're right, and I started thinking about just after I posted. I've gotten spoiled by lazy enumeration in a couple of other languages and I forgot about that detail. I've updated my answer to reflect that. See also http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6158

Comment: `.to_enum` is incredibly slow (at least in R1.8), simple loop is much  faster, so lazy stuff only looks nice (unless you want to re-implement it completely). At least it's my impression after I tried it.

Comment: Yeah, that lazy feature is only part of 2.0 right now. I'm not sure what the impact of to_enum would be, but I would imagine it's a bit better in 1.9.

Comment: (1..1000000000).to_enum.lazy.select{ |x| x%3==0}.take(10).to_a is pretty fast in ruby 2.0, for what it's worth... I suppose how expensive is going to depend on the complexity of turning a specific thing into an enum.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement `lazy_select`:

```
module Enumerable
  def lazy_select
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      each do |e|
        yielder.yield(e) if yield(e)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then things like

```
(1..10000000000).to_enum.lazy_select{|e| e % 3 == 0}.take(3)
# => [3, 6, 9]
```

execute instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an Enumerable-like extension which has your desired selectn semantics:

```
module SelectN
  def selectn(n)
    out = []
    each do |e|
      break if n <= 0
      if yield e
        out << e
        n -= 1
      end
    end
    out
  end
end

a = (0..9).to_a
a.select{ |e| e%3 == 0 } # [0, 3, 6, 9]
a.extend SelectN
a.selectn(1) { |e| e%3 == 0 } # [0]
a.selectn(3) { |e| e%3 == 0 } # [0, 3, 6]

# for convenience, you could inject this behavior into all Arrays
# the usual caveats about monkey-patching std library behavior applies
class Array; include SelectN; end
(0..9).to_a.selectn(2) { |e| e%3 == 0 } # [0,3]
(0..9).to_a.selectn(99) { |e| e%3 == 0 } # [0,3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess broken loop can be done in old-fashioned loop style with `break` or something like this:

```
n = 5
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].take_while { |e| n -= 1; n >= 0 && e < 7 }
```

In functional language this would be recursion, but without TCO it doesn't make much sense in Ruby.

**UPDATE**

`take_while` was stupid idea as dbenhur pointed out, so I don't know anything better than a loop.

Comment: this isn't equivalent to select{}.take(n) it will stop taking at the first element which doesn't pass the condition

Answer (score 0):

Why not flip this around and do the #take before the #select:

```
my_array.take(n).select { |elem| ... }
```

That will ensure you only do your computation for `n` number of items.

**EDIT:**

Enumerable::Lazy is known to be slower, but if your computation is known to be more computationally expensive than the lazy slowness, you can use the Ruby 2.0 feature:

```
my_array.lazy.select { |elem| ... }.take(n)
```

See: http://blog.railsware.com/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/

Comment: Then you'll have to repeat the operation until you get the right count.

Comment: Doesn't work for the scenario where there might be items I wanted after the first `n`...

Comment: because it has nothing to do with what was asked, you need to apply `select` first and then `take(n)`, not the other way around

Comment: Ah, indeed. In that case you really need lazy enumeration.